# React JS Mapped Data Fecthing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am trying to make a web app and I am fetching data from some where as an array. I got urls from this array in each element. So I could not imagine how I should fetch data from the mapped urls.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`someurl`)
      .then((response) => setState(response.data));
  }, []);
```

I am fetching basically as above and putting the response in some state.

```
[{
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "delectus aut autem",
    "completed": false,
    "url": "fakeapi.com/user/1"
},
{
    "userId": 2,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "delectus aut autem",
    "completed": false,
    "url": "fakeapi.com/user/2"
}]
```

Then I am mapping the response and listing in table.
I want to fetch again via urls in response. I could not understand how should I do because I am putting each response in a state.How should I do it?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code get the user list first and then get the individual user info using the response.data url by the loop. Then finally it set to the setstate

```
   axios
          .get(`someurl`)
          .then(async (response) => {
            await response.data.map(async (data, index) => {
              await axios
               .get(data.url)
               .then((resp) => response.data[index].user_data = resp.data );
             })
             console.log(response.data)
             setState( prevData => [...prevData, response.data] );
          })
```

Comment: Not sure this is something the author wanted to get. I believe he rather wants to request "user details"

Comment: Yes I need to reach user details

Comment: Now you check @DogacTopay